# Using the nested_form gem, how do I create a valid link_to the "show" of a child object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I use nested forms gem a bunch, but I haven't needed to navigate to the "show" page for a nested resource. Is there a way to do that simply, in the same style as the link_to_remove feature?

Associations are all set up and I have nested routes set up, but I can't figure out how to get an id into the "link_to" call.

Thanks for your help!

```
    =f.fields_for :contacts do |cf|
      .singleContact
        =cf.label :"Email"
        =cf.text_field :email

      =cf.link_to "Show", client_contact_path(@client, cf.id)
      =cf.link_to_remove "Delete Contact", :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete this comment?'

      %hr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=link_to "Show", cf.object
```

Note that if you also use `link_to_add` in your view, then newly added children won't yet have an `id` until the form is submitted.  So you may also want to add a condition that hides the "Show" link when `cf.object.id` is `nil`.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much! So my `cf` is the formbuilder and `cf.object` is the actual underlying instance? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Including the output from `class` and `inspect` can be helpful in a view.  For example, if you temporarily include `=cf.class` or `=cf.object.inspect` they'll provide more info.